# How to store an AWS CLI query result to a GitHub environment variable to be used in the same workflow?

Tags: github-actions

I'm trying to query AWS to get a certain CloudFront Distribution Id and store it in a GitHub Actions environment variable so I could us it to invalidate that CloudFront Distribution. This is what I've tried so far:

- name: Store CloudFront Distribution Id in env variable

  ```
   env:
     DIST_ID: ""
   run: |
     aws cloudfront list-distributions --query "DistributionList.Items[*].{id:Id,origin:Origins.Items[0].Id}[?origin=='$AWS_S3_BUCKET'].id" --output text > "$DIST_ID"
  ```

Any ideas on how I can accomplish this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set an environment variable from a script, it's easiest to append it to the special file behind `$GITHUB_ENV` as described in the [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-environment-variable):

```bash
echo "{environment_variable_name}={value}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

In your case, this would mean:

```yaml
steps:
  - run: |
     DIST_ID=$(aws cloudfront list-distributions --query "DistributionList.Items[*].{id:Id,origin:Origins.Items[0].Id}[?origin=='$AWS_S3_BUCKET'].id" --output text)
     echo "DIST_ID=$DIST_ID" >> $GITHUB_ENV
  - run: echo ${{ env.DIST_ID }}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, I get a shell check error the $GITHUB_ENV needs to be in double quotes. The run echo command result is: 
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
  env:
    AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: us-east-1
    AWS_REGION: us-east-1
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ***
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ***
    DIST_ID:  <----- this is blank.  If I run the aws cli command locally it works. I'm stumped.

Comment: I figured out why DIST_ID was empty. I had to set a default DIST_ID env variable before my jobs workflow. For some reason declaring it in the previous step it was not available in the next step as per the docs.